# HashSet and Display on JList

Tags: java, swing, vector, jlist, hashset

I have a question about hashSet.
I am trying to make a chatting program and want real time update.

Currently, I use Vector and Multi thread to store user names. By the way, Can I use HashSet instead of Vector?

my simple code dealing with Vector is below,

```
private JList userListMain = new JList();
private Vector userVC = new Vector();

userVC.add(UserAll+" (Me)");
userListMain.setListData(userVC);
```

Is there any way to change Vector in HashSet?

Comment: Write your own `ListModel` backed by a `HashSet`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I don't think you can with a HashSet. It would have to be a NavigableSet of some sort like a TreeSet.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Didn't say it would be a good idea ;) - Actually, the problem with either would be the ability to get the individual elements in sequential order...

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's why an ordered set is imperative, but a TreeSet **is** ordered, so no problem there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But it raises the question of efficiency, as you would need to iterate the `Set` each time `getElementAt` is called, that's not pretty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. If you don't want to use a Vector, then you'll have to create your own ListModel class, i.e., a class that implements the ListModel interface, and one requirement of this interface is that the elements can be reliably ordered. A HashSet would not work for this, however a TreeSet or some other SortedSet probably could be used as your model's data nucleus. Note that this of course isn't as simple as just creating your TreeSet and passing it into your JList's constructor, and your model class should probably extend `AbstractListModel<E>` in order to gain all the listener handling and notification handling code that it makes available.

Comment: I would say the issue with any type of set would the ability to support the `getElementAt` method, as none of the `Set` implementations I'm aware of have any kind of `get` method.  I guess you could wrap it in some kind of `List`, but that's an expensive operation...